# How do I keep my leopard geckos cage warm without a heat mat or bulb?

Tags: health, psychology, containment, leopard-geckos, equipment

I bought my gecko recently and had a bulb that worked fine, but it broke so I ordered a new one along with a heat mat, but they have not arrived. In the mean time, how can I keep it’s cage warm or can I? Will this affect its behaviour as it’s already very scared and doesn’t like loud noises.

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, are there incandescent bulbs available where you live? One could use a simple incandescent bulb as heat source. On the other hand, LED and fluorescent bulbs cannot be used like that because they emit almost no heat.

Comment: you could fill stable plastic bottles with warm water (not hot!) and lay them into the cage. you need to change them a lot, but it is better than nothing.